# Laplace Transform Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I was looking in my differential equations textbook and I found an interesting problem and I have no idea on how to approach it. I am supposed to let $F(s) = \mathcal{L} \{f(t) \} $ where $f(t)$ is piecewise continuous and of exponential order on $[0,\infty)$. Show that

$$\mathcal{L} \left\{ \int^{t}_{0} f(\tau)\space\text{d}\tau  \right\}  = \frac{1}{s} F(s)$$

is true.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Use the definition of the Laplace transform and integrate by parts.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/538959)

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky: It is not the complete solution, which in this case I think is desirable because with a little help the OP can figure it out by him-/herself. We generally don't provide full answers to homework-like or very basic problems.